# Difference between ::class vs ::className() in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

i know both gives same results but i am looking forward to hear about performance.

i am not sure but i think..

- "`MyClass::className()`" cause that class file to be loaded as well (its Yii function whom body is just simply `get_called_class()`)
- "`MyClass::class`" i think this php's native class property don't load class php file and just return its name based on current namespace or `use`.

Let me know if i am right? or highlight your knowledge please.

There are many places where we just want full qualitfied class name even it's not going to be used that time. but i also don't like putting hardcoded strings (due to hard refactoring)

Comment: A recommended practice is to call Xyz::className() to get the class name string so that you can receive IDE auto-completion support as well as error detection at compiling stage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes i just found i was right.

PHP's native class property is performance saving..(PHP 5.5+)

see here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class.name

so this don't cause class file to be loaded, so even if class doesn't exists it will return full className

> Note: The class name resolution using ::class is a compile time
>   transformation. That means at the time the class name string is
>   created no autoloading has happened yet. As a consequence, class names
>   are expanded even if the class does not exist. No error is issued in
>   that case.

Comment: The Yii function is abstracted and so can be changed in the future. Using `::class` disables this ability. You should also benchmark the two versions.

Answer (score 0):

[get_called_class()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-called-class.php) is for using in static methods.

Yii uses [autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) so the classes are loaded anyway. So there is no significant time difference between these both commands.

It's more important to look on the performance on your own code. And check and understand these performance tuning links for Yii 2.0: [Yii2-Docs: Performance Tuning](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-performance-tuning.html) and [Yii2-Docs:Lazy Loading and Eager Loading](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#lazy-eager-loading)

Comment: do you know any reference regarding MyClass::class

Comment: i know well about Yii's className and all about performance i want to know more about that php's native class property

Comment: sure, but i claim that performance is not significant because yii uses autoloading.

Comment: i know about get_called_class(). i told get_called_class() is being used.. but and you are claiming about perforamance which is wrong..as i just found an answer that ::class don't load php file while ::className() cause file loading.... so how can you say  that performance is not affected