# yii2 displaying username instead of user id

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm using [yii2-user-management](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-user-management) from webvimark to develop my project.

I also use [BlameableBehavior](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-blameablebehavior) to record data changes.

When I view the data, it displays the user id in the created_by and updated_by fields.

The question is how can I display the username instead of the id in the view code?

Comment: use your relations defined in the model

Comment: can you please accept the answer if it helped you out? it might help others looking for the same solution

Answer (score 0):

Define relations in your model like below

```
public function getCreator(){
    return $this->hasOne(User::class,['id','created_by']);
}

public function getModifier(){
    return $this->hasOne(User::class,['id','updated_by']);
}
```

**Note : if you are on an earlier version of php like 5.6 or before you can use `::className()` instead of `::class`. for difference see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378133/difference-between-class-vs-classname-in-yii2)**

Then use your relation in the view to display the `username` field instead of the user id, i assume you are using the `DetailView`

```
 <?php echo DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'creator.username',
            'modifier.username',
        ],
 ]);
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight @Muhammad!

i updated your code to:
`public function getCreator() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'created_by']);
    }

    public function getModifier() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'updated_by']);
    }`

Comment: `className()` was in `php 5.6` i have moved to 7.2 thats why used `class` @kputra

Comment: See the note i have highlighted in the answer @kputra